# Flex: How to set the text of label in for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a label in datagrid column. I want to set value to the label such that the label value will increment for each row according to the number of rows in grid. 
I wrote a simple for loop like this

```
for(i=1;i<=invArrayCol.length;i++)
{
srno.text=""+i;
}
```

where srno is id given to the label and invArrayCol is the ArrayCollectionObject which is the dataprovider to the grid. It shows me this error

access to undefined property srno

Comment: As per the error, you are not accessing it the right way.

Comment: Share some more code.  The loop looks solid, but what is srno and where is it defined [in relation to your loop]?  You won't be able to loop over items in a dataProvider and access renderers.  I suspect you may benefit from some research into renderer recycling.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html#WS5ED0A932-BA59-4a77-9A9D-3745FE21D1E9

Comment: Yah rather annoying that the BaseListData doesn't extend from or share the properties of fl.controls.ListData seeing as how that has a index value that is relevant to the dataprovider of the List.  This actually brings up an error in their documentation on the ListData within mx package which inherits from BaseListData which has the right information, the rowIndex supplied by that object is the index relative to what is visible not the DP.  Regardless your error is that srno is being used out of scope, you need to provide the code and it's relative location to the snippet you posted above.

Comment: As flextras has stated learn about item renderers and how they are recycled, understand this and you'll see you can (if you choose) retrieve the index for display in the renderer's set data function doing something like this:  someLabel.text = listData.owner.dataProvider.getItemIndex(data); or you can pre-process the DP to setup the counts, or you could use a static var in the class to have each object up the counter as it's created if the objects are created in the order they're entered in the DP... solution 1 costs CPU but is most robust in terms of re-sorting etc.